# Webserver to serve Python script

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Python script that I'd like to be run from the browser, it seem mod_wsgi is the way to go but the method feels too heavy-weight and would require modifications to the script for the output. I guess I'd like a php approach ideally. The scripts doesn't take any input and will only be accessible on an internal network.

I'm running apache on Linux with mod_wsgi already set up, what are the options here?

Comment: What is the output; is it something you can use a template to do a generate HTML structure, and populate elements?

Comment: I should have been clearer it's just plain text, the script just `print` stuff to `stdout` I just was a quick and simple way to display the output through the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go the micro-framework approach just in case your requirements change - and you never know, it may end up being an app rather just a basic dump... Perhaps the simplest (and old fashioned way!?) is using CGI:

- Duplicate your script and include `print 'Content-Type: text/plain\n'` before any other output to `sys.stdout`
- Put that script somewhere apache2 can access it (your cgi-bin for instance)
- Make sure the script is executable
- Make sure `.py` is added to the Apache CGI handler

But - I don't see anyway this is going to be a fantastic advantage (in the long run at least)

Comment: It really does need to be a short term dump so this is perfect.

Comment: @sudo_O I should note it's not tested though... but in theory should work (or at least enough for you to find working configs/examples)

Comment: Apart from `call(['/bin/svn','update','/path/to/repo'])` any ideas why this isn't executed?

Comment: @sudo_O This is where it gets tricky (debugging is a pain), it could be because apache is the owner of the interpreter and that user/group doesn't have access to the repo.... Simple work arounds like this are a bit harder to debug, but there is the `cgitb` module that may come in useful for handling tracebacks (but maybe start with the response and return code of the `call` for pointers)

Comment: You're right the `apache` user didn't have rights to the repo and I wasn't seeing any output because my scripts wasn't handling the output from the subprocess. Anyway all sorted now, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

You could use any of python's micro frameworks to quickly run your script from a server.  Most include their own lightweight servers.

From [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) home page documentation

```
import cherrypy
class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        # run your script here
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

ADditionally python provides the tools necessary to do what you want in its standard library
using [HttpServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html)

A basic server using [BaseHttpServer](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer):

```
import time
import BaseHTTPServer


HOST_NAME = 'example.net' # !!!REMEMBER TO CHANGE THIS!!!
PORT_NUMBER = 80 # Maybe set this to 9000.


class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_HEAD(s):
        s.send_response(200)
        s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        s.end_headers()
    def do_GET(s):
        """Respond to a GET request."""
        s.send_response(200)
        s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        s.end_headers()
        s.wfile.write("<html><head><title>Title goes here.</title></head>")
        s.wfile.write("<body><p>This is a test.</p>")
        # If someone went to "http://something.somewhere.net/foo/bar/",
        # then s.path equals "/foo/bar/".
        s.wfile.write("<p>You accessed path: %s</p>" % s.path)
        s.wfile.write("</body></html>")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)
    print time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    print time.asctime(), "Server Stops - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
```

What's nice about the microframeworks is they abstract out writing headers and such (but should still provide you an interface to, if required)