# Schedule a python script to run on webserver

Tags: python, django, web-services, cgi, wsgi

I am in the process of writing a Python script, that I will want to run automatically, say every evening.

I intend to run it from server, partly because I have one so I may as well as it's always on, but also to learn how to do it, and this may at some point end up as a more full 'web app' - for now though it's just reading some data, and sending an email.

[Solutions I've come across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841206/webserver-to-serve-python-script) have ranged from cgi, wsgi, to 'microframeworks'. I'm also loosely aware of Django (is that a 'microframework'?).

I don't know which I should be using for this simple task - I don't know if it even needs anything, can I just store it on the server and schedule it to run via cpanel?

Comment: You could just schedule a cronjob.

Comment: So I just put it `script.py` in some folder, and cron runs it fine?

Comment: Sure, there's no reason it wouldn't.

Comment: Great, thanks. Guess I just wasn't sure if it was capable - i.e. you can't run a `.py` without having Python installed on your PC.

Comment: Most (non-Windows) platforms have Python installed by default.

Comment: Well that qualifier actually makes it a minority of platforms..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running on a *nix server and your user account has permission, use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Edit your crontab using `$ crontab -e`

An entry along these lines will run your job at midnight each night:

`0 0 * * * python /path/to/myscript.py`

Comment: That's what I meant by my last sentence - I wasn't sure if it could 'run Python'.. it will just run the script as normal, as though I ran it locally?

Comment: Thanks also to @Blender who [answered at the same time in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804518/schedule-a-python-script-to-run-on-webserver?noredirect=1#comment32995113_21804518).